# Insert in another table when login Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use auth default login in Laravel 5.2, but I want when login to update or insert in another table on every user login.

I want to insert this when user login:

```
$sql = Counts::where('client_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
if (sizeof($sql) == 0) {
    $sql = new Counts();
    $sql->client_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $sql->save();
}
```

`Auth/Authcontroller.php` doesn't have login method ...

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Your question needs more details to get an answer. Check your route files to find out where your login endpoint is looking, and include the code in that controller in your question.

Comment: Laravel has a `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login` Event that gets triggered every time a user logs into your application. You can listen to this event and handle it in your Listener as the `$event` can pass the currently authenticated user that logged in.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/events#event-subscribers

Comment: @Joundill in routes file i have only Route::auth(); because i use make:auth not custom login, so how i can override the default login to trigger whenever user login.

Comment: @Nathan can you give please a real example please ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `AuthController`, override `postLogin` method from `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` like so:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
        {
            $counts = Counts::where('client_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
            if ($counts->isEmpty()) {
                $counts = new Counts();
                $counts->client_id = Auth::user()->id;
                $counts->save();
            }

            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        }

        return [
            'success' => false,
            'error' => 'Invalid credentials',
            'description' => 'Authentication failure'
        ];
    }
}
```

Simply copy paste this `postLogin` function at the bottom of your `AuthController` and it should work.

Comment: hi, i tested your code but not work.. not insert data after login can you check please ???

Comment: i think it does not execute postLogin in AuthController.php after override.. please help me ?.

Comment: can you contact me at https://join.slack.com/t/vue-vmr4432/shared_invite/zt-eau36fgx-k1KWjR7fmNdqfvlJouderw. I can help you better if I understand your problem in detail

Comment: ok i joined, how to send you message ? someone user comments above tell about event onuserlogin is it good please help me with working example.. thanks so much

Comment: sent you a message on slack

Answer (score 0):

In `Providers/EventServiceProvider.php` register a listener for the Login event:

```
 protected $listen = [
        'Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login' => [
            'App\Listeners\LoginListener',
        ],
    ];
```

Now create the actual listener for the Login event using the following command:

`php artisan make:listener LoginListener --event Illuminate\\Auth\\Events\\Login`

Now inside `Listeners/LoginListener.php`, code inside `public function handle(Login $event)` will be executed whenever a user logs into your application. You can get the user  ID that logged in with `$event->user->id`, you can test this with:

```
public function handle(Login $event)
{
   dd($event->user->id);
}
```

You can access email, name, etc from the user model using the event:

```
$event->user->name
$event->user->email
```

Ultimately, you can have something like this:

```
public function handle(Login $event)
 {
    $sql = Counts::where('client_id', $event->user->id)->get();
    if (sizeof($sql) == 0) {
        $sql = new Counts();
        $sql->client_id = $event->user->id;
        $sql->save();
    }
 }
```

Make sure to include `Counts` model in `LoginListener.php`:

```
use App\Counts;
```